# indexes: update on save or manually?

Tags: magento-1.8, indexing

I am on Magento CE 1.8

I am using a 3rd party database to feed my database, as a source for products
that change every day in new issues or updates (availability o not, etc..).

The question is about indexing: should I leave to indexing manually or on save ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

By and large...

1. **Update on save** will fire some (indexing related) events after a product is saved, so a full reindex won't be necessary after product updates.
2. **Manual** mode won't fire anything, so product updates will run faster, but you'll need to re-index everything in order to see some changes in front end.